# Xcode 13 build error - Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: react-native

Cannot build with xcode 13, I keep getting this error.

I have tried everything from this thread but nothing works, https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/161

I've nuked the repo pulled down again and still get the same error. I'm out of ideas, can anyone please help?

```
    /bin/sh -c /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-glxuojrfejxbhqgircpjgklctbto/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-85ABEEFECFDEC6A1611D2CF5A77EABBC.sh

/Users/xxx/apps/xxx/node_modules/react-native/scripts/generate-specs.sh: line 27: readlink: command not found
/Users/xxx/apps/xxx/node_modules/react-native/scripts/generate-specs.sh: line 27: dirname: command not found
/Users/xxx/apps/xxx/node_modules/react-native/scripts/generate-specs.sh: line 27: cd: : No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Using xcode 13, RN 64.2, macOS Big Sur 11.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by modifying `generate-specs.sh`

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32157#issuecomment-915165442

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try to add arm64 in debug & Release if excluded archivecture